# session logged out before session-timeout defined in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, session-timeout

I am facing a strange problem in my java web application, may be i am missing something. I am using Spring mvc 4, hibernate, java 8 (but not using spring security).

In `web.xml`, i have used the following to set session timeout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
....
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I have deployed the application with load balancer (where there is two VM). But the application logged out just after 2 minutes, whereas the logout time is 30 minutes?

I have gone through the [6 steps to investigate unexpected logouts in your Java web application](https://beyondscheme.com/2016/six-steps-to-investigate-unexpected-logouts) and follow the first 3 ways but no success.Can someone give me any suggestions?

Comment: Did you verify settings in the application server configuration?

Comment: @MallikarjunaReddy: if you can tell me what kind of settings I need to check, I will do it in sha Allah.